# How to create a notification without icon in the statusbar or simply hide it?

Tags: android, icons, android-notifications, android-statusbar

I'd like to know how to create a notification that doesn't show the icon in the statusbar.

There is a way to hide it?

Comment: use transparent image then ..

Comment: Do you mean you want only the notification text or nothing at all in the notification bar but only when you pull it down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to hide NotificationCompat.Builder notification\`s icon on status bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901312/android-how-to-hide-notificationcompat-builder-notifications-icon-on-status-bar)

Answer (score 34):

Since Android 4.1 (API level 16) it's possible to specify a notification's [`priority`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#priority). If you set that flag to [`PRIORITY_MIN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MIN) the notification icon won't show up on the statusbar.

```
notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MIN;
```

Or in case you use a `Notification.Builder`:

```
builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);
```

---

As of Android 8.0 Oreo (API level 26) you have to set the `importance` of the notification's `NotificationChannel` to [`IMPORTANCE_MIN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_MIN):

```
NotificationChannel channel = 
      new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
...
builder.setChannelId(channel.getId())
```

Comment: Is it works on Android 8+ with its new notification channels system?

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren I've updated the post to include the required setting for Android 8+

Comment: No the icon does not hide on Android 8+. It is just added at the bottom of my notification stack.

Answer (score 3):

`.setPriority` with parameter `PRIORITY_MIN` will make this possible.

```
NotificationCompat notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

                //Show the notification only in NotificationDrawer.
                //Notification will not be shown on LockScreen as well as Hidden Icon on StatusBar.
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)

                .build();
```

Comment: what's the from @Floern answer?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Mine is a complete code in case any new learner needs it.

Comment: It was not yesterday, until you've editted it 27 min. ago

Answer (score 1):

`NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED` works in my case

Comment: Amazing! And it's better yet! Stays kind of hidden in the bottom and must be opened to show everything. Perfect. Thank you! Wasn't expecting this from "unspecified" xD.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by having a total transparent image and use that as your icon. :)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to take any space on the statusbar. Maybe there isn't a way...

Answer (score -2):

**there is no way to show notification without icon.**

```
You can use transparent image. But, it take space of icon.
```

@CommonsWare: Since the primary point of raising a Notification is to put an icon in the status bar, there is usually no need to not put an icon in the status bar, unless it is interactive, such as a toggle or information notification that will always run and you might want on the pull down, but has no use for an icon.

[check this answer for more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15901492/1168654)