# How to show the Notification with no icon in status bar

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have read somewhere that we can use `IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED` to hide the icon in status bar  from notification. But it seems to not work in android 8 and above.

So I used `IMPORTANCE_LOW` ( as per the docs to hide the icon from status bar) but it doesn't worked for me.

But where as  many apps doesn't show any icon in status bar but  there notification is shown in Notification drawer.

[image: Such as This]

No Play Store icon in Status Bar
[image: Without any Icon in status bar.]

I have referred to many answers such as
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373786/how-to-create-a-notification-without-icon-in-the-statusbar-or-simply-hide-it) but it doesn't helped me

So please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done only for Android 8+. Or you have to root your phone and change to a newer version. You can also customize your apps when their developing time.
You can also edit all apps using this [Application](https://apk-editor.en.uptodown.com/android) and edit these applications and remove the icons from the notification part.
Also as a final way, You can edit the android configuration from the boot option.

Comment: Can you tell a way to make the icons hide without any root , external apps etc. Instead just by some sort of java codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any silent notification to minimize, all you have to do is to enter settings > notification > choose your app > show notification category then enable minimize notification option

Comment: I think that the person asking the question was interested in how to do this for an application *he was coding*, **not** as a user wanting to manage any notification.